# Mac App Certificates

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, certificate

Does anyone here know what exactly needs to be done for the second app we create regarding certificates? I already have a developer certificate I'm using to sign the installer for my second app, and it is working ok. Do I need to create TWO new certificates, or just one for the new app itself? Or neither? Any help?

UPDATE: I just submitted a brand new app using my developer certificate and new app ID. No errors or anything. Do I need to create a whole new certificate just for this separate app?

Zach

Comment: Apple's iOS developer portal does a good job of walking you through this.

Comment: @Mark: Actually, I disagree. I've been through it several times - otherwise, I wouldn't be on here. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you need only one developer certificate for all of your apps.
and you ned just one for the app itself.

go to work and relax :)

Comment: Hold on, I just submitted a brand new app with the same certificates I used for an old app - no errors or anything. Do i need a new certificate or are you thinking App ID?

Comment: For example, when I go to the certificate page, I see two: Both are in my name, and one is for app and other for installer. Can't I use these two for more than one app?